# Where did I went wrong $\int_{0}^{\infty}{\mathrm dx\over (1+x)^2}=0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Consider

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-x}\over 1+x}\mathrm dx=-eE_i(-1)=0.596347...\tag1$$
>
> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left({1\over 1+x}-e^{-x}\right)\cdot{\mathrm dx\over 1+x}=eE_i(-1)=-0.596347...\tag2$$
>
> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\mathrm dx\over (1+x)^2}=1\tag3$$

$E_i(x)$;Exponential integral

Here is the problem I am so confused with

$(1)+(2)$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-x}\over 1+x}\mathrm dx+
\int_{0}^{\infty}\left({1\over 1+x}-e^{-x}\right)\cdot{\mathrm dx\over 1+x}=0\tag4$$

Simplify $(4)$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\mathrm dx\over (1+x)^2}=0\tag5$$

$(5)$ supposed to $\color{red}1$.

Why did I went wrong?

Comment: $(2)$ cannot be right. The integral of a positive function over $\mathbb{R}^+$ cannot be negative.

Comment: This looks like one of the usual bugs in programs like Mathematica or whatever is used by Wolfram Alpha, say...

Comment: I check and check on wolfram integrator many times

Comment: You probably right @Don

Comment: Extneding @Don 's thoughts, I would recommend submitting a bug report.

Comment: @Bui Almost undoubtedly: the integrand in integral (2) is non-negative, so if it converges it can't possibly equal a negative number, as already commented and answered.

Comment: Mathematica $8$ returns $1+e\,\text{Ei}(-1)$ as a value of $(2)$, that is correct.

Comment: This is the link http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(1%2F(1%2Bx)-e%5E(-x))(1%2F(1%2Bx))dx,x%3D0+to+infty

Comment: It looks like Houston has a problem the old Houston did not have :D

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio That just made my day XD Odd that Mathematica would just drop that $+1$ part...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value for integral (2) you wrote is not correct.  On $[0,\infty)$, we must have $(1+x)^{-1} \ge e^{-x}$, because $$e^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!} \ge 1 + x.$$  Thus, the integrand is strictly nonnegative for all $x \ge 0$.

---

In *Mathematica* (Version 10.4 on my system), the command

```
Integrate[(1/(1 + x) - Exp[-x])/(1 + x), {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

returns `E ExpIntegralEi[-1]` which then evaluated numerically gives a negative real number.  However,

```
NIntegrate[(1/(1 + x) - Exp[-x])/(1 + x), {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

gives `0.403653` which is correct.  I suspect the issue has to do with branch cut evaluation.  It may have been fixed in subsequent versions.  Note that the correct value can be evaluated symbolically with the command

```
Integrate[1/(1 + x)^2, {x, 0, Infinity}] - Integrate[Exp[-x]/(1 + x), {x, 0, Infinity}]
```